# using swift, I'm simply trying to turn an else block in to a ternary operator

Tags: swift, ternary

```
   if bulletsOn == true {
            bullets -= 0.003
        } else {
            bullets += 0.001
        }
```

when I put in form of ternary like so, I get error from compiler.

```
    bulletsOn ? bullets -= 0.003 : bullets += 0.001
```

error: Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types '()' and 'CGFloat'

Comment: `bullets = bulletsOn ? bullets - 0.003 : bullets + 0.001`

Comment: `bullets += bulletsOn ? 0.001 : -0.003`

Comment: The issue there is the lack of a parentheses. `bulletsOn ? (bullets -= 0.003) : (bullets += 0.001)`. Btw `bulletsOn ? bullets -= 0.003 : (bullets += 0.001)` would work as well

Answer (score 1):

Ternary are just funny math operations so you need a value two be assigned to, a condition and the two values that can be assigned to it, but your two condition don't even return values, so

```
bullets += bulletsOn ? -0.003 : 0.001
```

would work